# Indentation is gone when copy-pasting from VS Code into LO Writer

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, indentation, libreoffice-writer

When I copy some code from the Visual Studio Code and paste it into Writer the colors are preserved but all indents are gone. When I paste as "Unformatted text" it preserves the indentation but the colors are gone. It happens only with VSCode (copy-pasting from PyCharm preserves both indents and colors, but I work in VSCode). Is it a bug? Any help is much appreciated.